# Why does this statement throw a null reference exception?

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, conditional-operator

This will throw a null reference exception when InnerException is null.

```
String s = " inner exception: " + e.InnerException == null ? "None" : e.InnerException.Message;
```

but this won't:

```
String s = " inner exception: " + (e.InnerException == null ? "None" : e.InnerException.Message);
```

Both of the above build fine. I can't figure out what the former is trying to do that would cause it to evaluate `e.InnerException.Message`. Why aren't they equivalent?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is because your first statement is evaluating `" inner exception: " + e.InnerException == null` to be `true` or `false`.  It's all about *operator precedence*, which is why the second works just fine due to the parenthesis (`(` and `)`).

[See this reference for Operator Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx).  The `+` operator is evaluated before the equality `==` operator.

Comment: That's why it is best to include brackets in non-obvious cases so you don't have to think about the operator precedence.

Answer (score 4):

It is due to operator precedence, in this case the `+` operator has higher precedence than the `==` operator so you need to use parenthesis to override the default precedence order so that the code is executed in the correct order.

You can read all about it in C# language specification:

[Operator precedence and associativity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323%28VS.71%29.aspx)

> When an expression contains multiple operators, the precedence of the
>   operators controls the order in which the individual operators are
>   evaluated.

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
String s = " inner exception: " + e.InnerException == null ? "None" : e.InnerException.Message;
```

Is probably being evaluated like this:

```
String s = (" inner exception: " + e.InnerException) == null ? "None" : e.InnerException.Message;
```

Answer (score 2):

Order of operations:

```
String s = " inner exception: " + e.InnerException == null ? "None" : e.InnerException.Message;
```

Is evaluated as `(" inner exception: " + e.InnerException) == null ?` which it's not.